# Design pattern for Immutable object with eventual immutability

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want to construct an object which I want to pass on to the rest of the application as an immutable object. However problem here is that some fields are directly available at object construction time whereas some require a response from an RPC call. RPC call takes some time to return and I do not want to block the callers during this time because I would like callers to use the fields which are passed in during the object construction time. I have a design in mind but wanted to know if there is a standard pattern.

Following example illustrates what I am looking for.

```
public class Player {
  private int name;  // Available at construction time
  private int age;   // Available at construction time

  private String profileUrl;  // Need to get this from an RPC call

  // useful for checking whether we have profileUrl 
  private boolean profileUrlAvailable = false; 

  Player(int name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  // usual getter methods

  // Package protected for immutability
  void setProfileUrl(String profileUrl) {
    this.profileUrl = profileUrl;
    this.profileUrlAvailable = true;
  }

  public boolean hasProfileUrl() {
    return profileUrlAvailable;
  }

  // throws if profile url is not yet available.
  public String getProfileUrl() {
    if (!profileUrlAvailable) {
       throw new IllegalStateException("Profile url not available");
    }
    return profileUrl;
  }
}
```

This example is not threadsafe, consider that it will be taken care of. To be able to let interested callers know when the profile url is available, I will expose a method to register callables which will be notified when the profileUrl is available.

I think this approach does not work well if I add few more fields similar to profileUrl which will eventually be available. I wanted suggestions on the ways to solve this.

Does it simplify if I make sure that all fields similar to profileUrl are made available at the same time (ie., they are set using a single method) ?

Comment: Why not use an interface to expose the methods that you want external code to use, and simply not expose the methods that make changes?

Comment: Sure, that would make sure it is not mutable to the external world. What do you think about the other part of the problem in dealing with eventually available fields : hasField(), getField() & notifying when the field is available. I could combine all such fields in an innerclass and set them in single call and notify the world when this is set. But is there any better way of doing it ?

Comment: Would something like the Builder Pattern work for you?

Comment: I believe Builder pattern would be useful if I have all the fields before creating the object. In my case, I have a few fields while instantiating the object and will be adding other fields later. I don't see a straightforward way of applying it unless you have a different idea.

Comment: Do you have access to the RPC statically? If you do, then there is already an answer that lies around that approach. I actually faced this kind of scenario in an enterprise scaled eCommerce platform application which I solved by *caching* most/some of the large data when the application initializes. I could share the code if you like to...

Answer (score 0):

Does [Lazy initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) suit your needs?

Code snippet:

```
public class Player {
private int name;  // Available at construction time
private int age;   // Available at construction time

private String profileUrl = null;  // Need to get this from an RPC call 

Player(int name, int age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

// usual getter methods

public String getProfileUrl() {
  if (profileUrl == null) {
     profileUrl = Remote.getProfileUrl();
  }
  return profileUrl;
 }
}
```

You would move your RPC to the accessor method, in this case `getProfileUrl`.
Only the first call would actually block waiting for the remote procedure to finish.

Other accessor methods for fields that require this kind of heavy initialization would look the same.

If you can use `Player` class this way and are able to cache `profileUrl` for future calls you would solve your problem and hit this pattern's goal.

Comment: This is a good answer. But don't you think that OP could have done it if he had access to RPC in that way?